# Why is my GSON Deserializer throwing a stack overflow for Option[SomeObject]?

Tags: scala, gson

I have a case class with an Option I am trying to serialize/deserialize.

```
case class Foo(
  bar: Option[OtherObject]
)
```

To do this I created a custom serializer like this...

```
class OptionSerializer extends JsonSerializer[Option[Any]] with JsonDeserializer[Option[Any]] {
  override def serialize(
                          t: Option[Any],
                          `type`: Type,
                          context: JsonSerializationContext
                        ): JsonElement = {
    if (t.isDefined) context.serialize(t.get)
    else null
  }

  override def deserialize(
                            json: JsonElement,
                            t: Type,
                            context: JsonDeserializationContext): Option[Any] = {
    if (json.isJsonNull) None
    else {
      context.deserialize(json, t)
    }
  }
}
```

Then register it like...

```
def getGson = {
  val gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
  gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(classOf[Option[Any]], new OptionSerializer)
  gsonBuilder.create()
}
```

But when I run I get...

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:48) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:65) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1003) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter$GsonContextImpl.deserialize(TreeTypeAdapter.java:162) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar:na]
    at com.....deserializer
```

I need to be able to handle optional arrays and objects.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried creating a specialized deserializer for Option[OtherObject]?

Comment: Any reason in particular why you're using gson? Native Scala libraries tend to work a lot better.

Comment: I would recommend you to do not use a **Java** library for deserializing **Scala** classes, rather use a **Scala** library which are also mature and production-ready, plus they are also more idiomatic and handle things like **Options** out of the box. Some of them are: `circe`, `play-json`, `uJson`. `jsoniter-scala`, _etc_.